# Is "long: 16byte on my system?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long* fp;
    while(1)
    {
        fp = (long* ) malloc (sizeof(long));
        printf("%d\t",fp);
    }
}
```

I ran this.
I got result such as:

```
1193392 1193408 1193424 1193440 1193456 1193472 1193488 1193504 1193520 1193536 1193552 1193568 1193584 1193600 1193616 1193632 1193648 1193664 1193680 1193696 1193712 1193728 1193744 1193760 1193776 1193792 1193808 1193824 1193840 1193856 1193872 1193888 1193904 1193920 1193936 1193952 1193968 1193984 1194000 1194016 1194032 1194048 1194064 1194080 1194096
```

Does this mean long on my system is 16 byte long?

thanks.

I just noticed that.. from the beginning part. the difference is 14, then it beomes to 16. bizarre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. It could indicate that the granularity of the allocator is 16 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't. It just means that `malloc()` returns 16-byte aligned blocks.

Also, you shouldn't print pointers with `%d`, you should use `%p` to print pointers.

To find out how large a `long` is,

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(long));
```

Answer (score 3):

What does `sizeof(long)` specifically report? I'd be surprised if it is 16 bytes.

Note from `malloc(3)`:

```
RETURN VALUE
   For calloc() and malloc(), return a pointer to the allocated
   memory, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable.
```

Your platform apparently requires 16 byte alignment for some objects, thus that is the granularity returned by `malloc(3)`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're invoking printf incorrectly; `%d` calls for an argument of type `int`, and passing something else (like `long *`) in invokes undefined behavior. You can't draw any real conclusions from it, in other words.

Instead do:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)fp);
```

Or even simply ask for what you want directly:

```
printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(long));
```

Also note that most systems have some additional overhead to malloc beyond the size of the object requested. On Linux glibc, each malloc must allocate a minimum of `2*sizeof(void*)` bytes, plus an additional `2*sizeof(void*)` bytes in overhead beyond what was requested (this is the current implementation; however this is undocumented and subject to change without notice). If your `void*` are 4 bytes long, this matches up with your observations nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%ld", sizeof(long));
}
```

Comment: Wrong type. `%zu`, not `%ld`, is for `size_t`. Or cast to a known type like `unsigned long` before printing.

Answer (score 0):

No. Rather, `malloc()` is required by the standard to return an address that is suitably aligned for *any* data type, so you are merely observing that the maximum alignment on your platform is 16.